# Failed to verified signed exe on Windows OS

Tags: javafx, signtool

I have created a JavaFX bundle on Windows7 OS and signed the .exe using signtool. The .exe is signed successfully but when verifying the .exe it is producing this error -

> SignTool Error: **WinVerifyTrust returned error: 0x800B010D Verifying:**
>   Application.exe **The certification path terminates with the test root which is not trusted with the current policy settings.**

I am using Application.p12 certificate.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using following command to verify -

```
signtool.exe verify /v /pa  Application.exe
```

This resolve verification error.